# Login and password program

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, authentication, passwords

I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: There is no row at
>   position 0.

I have pasted my code and I cant figure why I'm receiving this error message.

I know this is a very basic program but I'm just learning. :)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=B70143272PC4;Initial Catalog=TestDB1;Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select employeeid,username, password from Employeeinfo where [UserName] = '" + textBox1+ "' and [Password] = '" +textBox2.Text+"'", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 ff = new Form2();
    ff.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please check your Username and Passowrd");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `Text` property of the `TextBox1`. It should be:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select employeeid,username, password from Employeeinfo where [UserName] = '" + textBox1.Text+ "' and [Password] = '" +textBox2.Text+"'", con);
```

But you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select employeeid,username, password from Employeeinfo where [UserName] = @username and [Password] = @password", con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if I understood this correctly and you want to check if the datatable has any results, instead of `if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")`

use `if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)`

Rows has a count property that tells you how many rows there are in the collection.